# spring return object on button click out of list

Tags: java, spring, web

Hi guys hope you can help me, because i cant get further at the moment

I have my Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/kundenseite", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String kundenLogin(ModelMap model) {
        if(kundeComponent.getKunde() != null) {
        List<Restaurant> restaurants = restaurantService.alleRestaurants();
        model.addAttribute("restaurants", restaurants);
        return "kundenseite";
        }else {
            return "redirect:/kunde/login";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/kundenseite", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String kundenLoginAnswer(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute Restaurant restaurant) {
        System.out.println(restaurant.toString());
        return "kundenseite";
```

And my jsp file

```
<%@ include file="common/header.jspf" %>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>MiMiMi Lieferservice</h1>
  <p>Der schnellste Lieferservice von Passpick</p> 
</div>
<div style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; width: 33%">
<h2 style="text-align: center">Restaurant wählen</h2>
<div class="well">

<c:forEach items="${restaurants}" var="restaurant">
<form:form modelAttribute="${restaurant}" method="post">

<div style="margin-top: 8px" class=col-sm-4 >${restaurant.name}</div>
<div style="margin-top: 8px" class=col-sm-4 >${restaurant.restaurantTyp}</div>
<button type="submit">Bestellen</button>
</form:form>
<br style="clear:both;" />

</c:forEach>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the user presses a button i want to return a restaurant.
But i don't know how to make that happen, my thought was to use a form but i cant get it to send a complete restaurant object back

If there is no solution for this i have to write the id with the button.

Answer (score 0):

You need input hidden inside the form tab as below input hidden:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="${restaurant.name}">
<input type="hidden" name="restaurantTyp" value="${restaurant.restaurantTyp}">
```

Comment: And what if i don't want to have inputs,because i only need 2 of them 2 show for info ? ?

Comment: If you don't add the input, you cannot get the value in Controller. I recommend to get the complete restaurant add just a Id or Key as input hidden. Then in the server side get by id again.